# DateTime in ListBox C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, listbox

I would like to fill a listBox with DateTime. 
So firstly, I've my code in ASP.NET

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;
            <asp:ListBox 
                ID="ListBoxDate" 
                runat="server" 
                AutoPostBack="True"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBoxDate_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            </asp:ListBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is in C# the method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxDate.DataSource = GetAllDate(); /* it returns a list of objects Date (which is a class with an attribute DateTime) */
    ListBoxDate.DataTextField = "_Date";
    ListBoxDate.DataValueField = "_Date";
    ListBoxDate.DataBind();
}
```

And the method ListBoxDate_SelectedIndexChanged when I click on the event :

```
protected void ListBoxDate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Date date= new Date()
    {
        _Date = ListBoxDate.SelectedValue,
    };
}
```

And when I click on my date, I just recover an empty string and not a DateTime or a string containing the date. (the listbox is OK when it displays on my browser)

I did the same principle with other attributes wich are string and it was OK. The problem is really the use of DateTime.

So, how can I recover the Date in after clicking on the listBox ?

Comment: What are you binding to?

Comment: Where is the `DateTime`?

Comment: What do you have in your DataSource?

Comment: What does `GetAllDate()` return?

Comment: here is a good tutorial on how to use `ListBox` I think that it will give you an idea on how to structure your code as well as code the events when clicking. when you get more experienced you can also research hot to Bind `List<T>` to a `ListBox` http://www.dotnetperls.com/listbox

Comment: benygel please show all relevant code as well as the event(s) and code within the event(s) that you are calling what is `_Date` is that where and how is it declared..?

Comment: if `_Date` is a DateTime DataType then `list.SelectedValue;` would need to be Cast as a DateTime for example `var selectedValue = (DateTime)list.SelectedItem;` also where are you using `date`

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried tha cast and also "_Date = DateTime.Parse(list.SelectedValue)" but it is not OK because the string is empty, so the cast is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Page_Load`, you have to check if is not a postback before databinding the ListBox. Otherwise, the `ListBox` will be repopulated before entering `ListBoxDate_SelectedIndexChanged` and the `SelectedValue` value will be lost:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {
       ListBoxDate.DataSource = GetAllDate(); /* it returns a list of objects Date   (which is a class with an attribute DateTime) */
       ListBoxDate.DataTextField = "_Date";
       ListBoxDate.DataValueField = "_Date";
       ListBoxDate.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Have in mind that the `SelectedValue` property is a String, you'll have to parse its value to obtain a DateTime. You can using `DateTime.Parse()` for that.

Comment: Great ! There's no longer problem. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @benygel Good to hear it worked. "_When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer._" - from FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask